# Confused with Clustering

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-science

I am getting so confused with clustering in data science process. 
We know that the process of grouping similar points in a 2D space is based on this formula:

```
distance = sqrt( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 )
```

But in introducing inputs to the sklearn we just feed the x-axis values :( what happened to the y-axis values?

for example we have the following data base:

```
index    x     y
------------------
  0      5     8
  1      6     9
  2      7     10
```

and we introduce x to the KMeans

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(2)
kmeans.fit(df["x"])
```

How can it calculate distance without having y values?

Comment: Well, it looks like you are only passing it the x values, so it is possible to run clustering algorithms in 1-dimension.  (do a search on it.)  This would be akin to having all the y-values as zero if you are thinking about it in 2D.

Comment: In the examples from scikit, they're using a numpy array of points for the `fit` function, not just the x values. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Comment: That was a stupid question. I did a horrible mistake :|

Answer (score 1):

KMeans clustering can be done in any number of dimensions. As you said, the distance can be calculated using the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance). This distance can be calculated for any number of dimension. You passed one array, so in this case it's just one dimension, so the formula would simplify to:

```
distance = sqrt((x2-x1)^2)
```

Which is really just the absolute value of (x2-x1)